# changing page in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to set up a JS when users press the button, it would redirect them to the homepage, which called index.html

```
<form method="confirm" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:100px; margin-bottom: 100px; font-size: 30px; color: black;">
<fieldset id="confirm"> 
    <legend>NOTIFICATION</legend>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <h1>THANK YOU FOR SIGNING IN</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Return to homepage" onclick="return return1();">
    <script>
            function return1()
            {
                window.location.href = 'index.html';
            }
    </script>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
</fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: when i clicked the button, it does not redirect me to the index page:)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `method` attribute can only be `post` or `get`, not `confirm`. Look at the difference here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: @PéBin How did you solve it? If some answer helped you out you can accept it so the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes here.

The error you get is because you use a submit input button inside a form and the button will try to evaluate your form submission. To prevent that you have to return false on your function.

```
<script>
        function return1()
        {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

But if you want to do a button that simply will redirect to another page you should not use a form and a submit button but just a normal input button

```
<input type="button" value="Return to homepage" onclick="return1();">
```

If you want to use the form because you want to evaluate some data you need to put your page on the `<form>` in the `action` field, without using the script

Also confirm is not accepted you should use `GET`or `POST`.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return false to the function to disable the default event on submit(page refresh)

```
function return1()
        {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
window.location.href = 'index.html';
```

with:

```
window.open('INDEX.HTML');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code redirects me to index.php which sits at the same level as index.html and index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head> 
        <body>

           <form action="check.php" method="post" id="re">
               <fieldset id="confirm"> 
               <legend>NOTIFICATION</legend>
               <table>
               <tr>
               <td>
               <h1>THANK YOU FOR SIGNING IN</h1>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <td>
               <input type="submit" value="Return to homepage">
               </td> 
               </tr>


               </table>
               </fieldset>
           </form>

               <script src="index.js"></script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

The JS file

```
function _x(elem){
    return document.getElementById(elem);
}

var x = _x("re");
    x.onsubmit = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "index.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change your input type `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="button" value="Return to homepage" onclick="return return1();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You change code

```
<input type="submit" value="Return to homepage" onclick="return return1();">
```

=> `<a href="index.html" class="btn">Return to homepage</a>`

With you type css ".btn" see like a button

Note : In form, you should not put  or  to redirect without submit form.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<script language="javascript">

function return1()
{
  window.location="yourpage.html";
}
</script>
```